# Data from the state is not processed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

everyone! I've encountered such an issue: I'm trying to create a dropdown list during the component initialization. I subscribe to an observable that stores states and attempt to pass processed values to this.data.areaOptions. However, the code isn't executing; only the log for `this.appFacade.state$` works in the console. Moreover, if I check the observable and inspect `availableDistributorsState.value` (which I need), it is in the following state:

> Observable {source: BehaviorSubject}    source: BehaviorSubject
> closed: false  currentObservers: null  hasError: false isStopped:
> false observers: (7) [SafeSubscriber, SafeSubscriber, SafeSubscriber,
> SafeSubscriber, SafeSubscriber, SafeSubscriber, SafeSubscriber]
> thrownError: null
>
> _value: AppState   actionType: "[App Store] Load User Success"   availableDistributorsState: AvailableDistributorsState
> 8.1.      loaded: false
> 8.2.      loading: false
> 8.3.      [[Prototype]]: Object

```
private initForm(): void {
    this.cardForm.get('area')?.enable();
    const id: string | undefined = this.data.item?.id;

    if (id !== undefined && this.data.mode === 'edit') {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log(this.appFacade.state$);

      **this.appFacade.state$
        .subscribe((appState: AppState): void => {
          console.log(appState.availableDistributorsState.value)
          this.data.areaOptions = appState.availableDistributorsState.value
            ?.map((distributor: IAvailableDistributor): ISelectedOption => ({
              console.log(distributor.id) ;
              value: distributor.id,
              label: distributor.name,
            })) ?? [];
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });**

      this.storesAndLeftoversFacade.loadStore(id)
        .subscribe((store: Store): void => {
          this.cardForm.patchValue(store);
          this.loading = false;
          this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });
    }
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

what could be the problem ?

I checked the logic, it should work, to be honest, I'm a complete newbie. Also, if you remove the status check, etc., the situation doesn't change. Perhaps there's an issue with asynchronicity? But if you use mock data, the dropdown list is created, so it seems the problem is in the state.

Comment: appState.availableDistributorsState.loaded to ensure that the data is available before processing it. This can help prevent issues when the observable emits values with action types unrelated to your use case.

Comment: Please ensure that AppState and related classes are correctly configured and that the observable emits the expected data.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, the problem really was with observable